# GCP: no redirect of domain to ip

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns-zone

I'm using google cloud platform, have a vm instance with external ip 34.141.104.0 and a domain charec.net, which should be redirecting to that ip.

I have created a cloud DNS Zone (public, DNSSEC off) and have four records in it:

```
charec.net.       A              34.141.104.0
charec.net.       SOA            ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 1 21600 3600 259200 300
charec.net.       NS             ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com.
                                 ns-cloud-a2.googledomains.com.
                                 ns-cloud-a3.googledomains.com.
                                 ns-cloud-a4.googledomains.com.
www.charec.net.   CNAME          charec.net.
```

But nonetheless, `dig charec.net` has no answer section, it just returns:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.16.15-Debian <<>> charec.net
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 52209
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;charec.net.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
charec.net.     300 IN  SOA ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 2 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 67 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.188.1#53(192.168.188.1)
;; WHEN: Di Nov 09 10:19:03 CET 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 132
```

What do I do wrong? What can I do, to get more information, why is it not redirecting to the ip? I created that record two days ago, so the 24 h have already past.

Comment: You are querying the local resolver. When debugging query the authoritative name server. In your question show the command as well. Is this a new domain? Verify that the authoritative name servers point to your DNS server. Edit your question with more details.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved my issue after contacting gcp support - GCP has two options for redirecting Domain to an ip. You can create an DNS Zone, or you can just put an A Record in google domains in the DNS Settings - but only the Domain DNS Setting OR the DNS Zone applies.

In GCP Domain -> Network services -> cloud domains click on your domain and "edit DNS Details".

There you can configure either the zone, that is applied for your domain, or the google domain settings.